# Sanitize MongoDb with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this code:

```php
$pid = $_GET["pid"];

$manager = new MongoDb\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$query = new MongoDb\Driver\Query(["pid" => $pid]);

$rows = $manager->executeQuery("shop.products", $query);
```

Is there a way to sanitize the `$pid` with php? Thank you.

Comment: Sanitize for what purpose? Your query should be fine as written.

Comment: I think my code is injection vulnerable

Comment: Why do you think that?

Answer (score 1):

You can cast `$pid` to a string in the query to guard against it being a mapping.